# x must be < bitmap.width()

Tags: java, android

I'm building an app that takes a picture, displays the picture and then once tapped, returns the color of the picture wherever it was tapped.

It gets as far as the tap before it crashes. I get the error that x must be <  bitmap.width()

As far as my understanding goes, if I'm clicking within the bitmap and gaining the coordinate, how can it be greater than the bitmap.width()?

I'll post my code below and see if anyone can help me make sense of what I'm doing wrong.

http://pastebin.com/scwiuM4w

Comment: you should get the x position with respect to ImageView. not with Respect to Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onTouchEvent` returns x, y within the Activity not within your `ImageView`.

See from `Activity.onTouchEvent` help: Called when a touch screen event was not handled by any of the views under it. This is most useful to process touch events that happen outside of your window bounds, where there is no view to receive it.

Comment: I mended my code to include the 'imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()' directly after it displays the picture in imageView.

But now I'm getting y must be < imageView.height()

Comment: The issues was with the bitmap ultimately. The picture I was taking was only a temporary photo and taken at a very small size.

To gain a larger image I had to save the file to a photo directory on the sdcard.

Comment: Can you please help with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370470/how-to-fix-dragging-outside-of-the-layout-and-near-the-edge-fcing-the-app